# Input Type Date validation 18 years old below

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm having trouble with validation of input type="date". It shouldn't accept 18 years old below. Could you please help me? Thank you.

I google and search the forum I haven't found the answer. 
I tried to validate it in the next page using PHP but my professor told me I must validate it in the same page. Like onchange it must be validated.

```
<input type="date" name="bday" id="bday" value="">
```

Comment: Use javascript for the validation

Comment: Use jquery datepicker for that input field

Comment: time to learn about javascript `Date` object

Comment: Yes Sir I'm trying to learn it

Comment: how you want the validation to be? 18 years below in the sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make use of javascript. If you want to accept birthdate of only 18 years and above then try following javascript code.
put `onblur="return dobcheck()"` in `bday` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dobcheck()
{
    var birth = document.getElementById('bday')
    if(birth != "")
    {

        var record=document.getElementById('bday').value.trim();
        var currentdate=new Date();    
        var day1 = currentdate3.getDate();   
        var month1 = currentdate3.getMonth();
        month1++;     
        var year11 = currentdate3.getFullYear()-17;
        var year2= currentdate3.getFullYear()-100;   
        var record_day1=record.split("/");
        var sum=record_day1[1]+'/'+record_day1[0]+'/'+record_day1[2];  
        var current= month1+'/'+day1+'/'+year11;
        var current1= month1+'/'+day1+'/'+year2;
        var d1=new Date(current)
        var d2=new Date(current1)
        var record1 = new Date(sum);      
        if(record1 > d1)
        {

            alert("Sorry ! Minors need parential guidance to use this website");
            document.getElementById('bday').blur();
            document.getElementById('bday').value="";
            document.getElementById('bday').focus();
            return false;
        }
    } 
}
</script>
```

i hope that now you will get it...

Comment: Sir I don't know how to use this. Here is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/92Y2L/

thank you so much sir

Answer (score 5):

In case you are allowed to use HTML5, it is pretty simple. You can simply use the max attribute:

```
<input id="bday" type="date" max="1995-12-31" required="" />
```

In case you have to do it dynamic you can create the max attribute dynamically.

I made an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/wpb54/
http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/wpb54/4/

Answer (score 3):

I know it's too late :D But may be, it would help others :)

```js
    $(function(){
        var dtToday = new Date();
    
        var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;// jan=0; feb=1 .......
        var day = dtToday.getDate();
        var year = dtToday.getFullYear() - 18;
        if(month < 10)
            month = '0' + month.toString();
        if(day < 10)
            day = '0' + day.toString();
     var minDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
        var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
     $('#dob').attr('max', maxDate);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="dob">
```

Comment: jQuery is superfluous here. Simply replace `$(function(){/*…*/})` with `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){/*…*/}` and `$('#dob')` with `document.querySelector('#dob')`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
        $year=(int)date("Y");
        $year-=18;
        $year=(String)$year;
        $year=$year.'-'.date("m").'-'.date("d");
        echo "<input type='date'  id='dob' name='dob' 
max='$year' required>";
        ?>
```

Comment: This is too late but i find it much easier and simple .  This may be useful for new ones  : -)       Its my own code  :  -)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).